# are there any free websphere 5 profiling tools?

Tags: jakarta-ee, profiling, websphere

i am looking for a client application that can connect to an EAR file within websphere and give me information like memory usage, heap size, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found Tivoli Performance Viewer as part of the Websphere suite, but it looks a little clunky.

Answer (score 0):

ManageEngine's Applications Manager does provide basic information like Heap usage and other performance stats. It is available [here](http://manageengine.adventnet.com/products/applications_manager/), however it is not a profiling tool. It is a monitoring tool.